# How to best create an array of objects from a objects in one array that are not included in a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want an array that contains objects from the `scrape` object that are not present in the `old` object.   The arrays I'm actually working with contains nearly 100 objects.

The code below works, but I wonder if there's a more efficient way of getting the same result?

```
var old = [
  {a: 6, b: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 1}, 
  {a: 3, b: 3}
]

var scrape = [
  {a: 1, b: 1}, 
  {a: 5, b:5}
]

var nogood = []
var good =[]

scrape.forEach(es => {
  old.forEach(e => {
    if(e.a == es.a) {
      nogood.push(es)
    }
  })
})
console.log(nogood)

nogood.forEach(main =>   
  good = scrape.filter(e=> e.a!=main.a)  
)
console.log(good)
```

This is what I expect and what I'm getting:

```
good = {a:5, b:5}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would approach this with:

```
const old = [
  {a: 6, b: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 1}, 
  {a: 3, b: 3}
];

const scrape = [{a: 1, b: 1}, {a: 5, b:5}];

for (const item of old) {
  for (const i in scrape) {
    if (JSON.stringify(item) === JSON.stringify(scrape[i])) {
      scrape.splice(i, 1); //delete the previously scraped item
    }
  }
} 

console.log(scrape); //{a: 5, b:5}
```

The benefits to this approach are:

- You don't care what properties the objects you're comparing have,
     you just care about whether they're identical.
- It's fast
     (comparing JSON is generally faster than traversing the objects to
     compare each property).
- It's more succinct to splice the scrape
     array rather than adding the 'good' and 'nogood' arrays to arrive at
     a filtered scrape array.

Possible deal breaker is if the objects you're comparing contain methods, in which case comparing them via JSON is not the correct approach.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Answer (score 1):

If we have arrays `old` and `scrape` to be of size `M` and `N`, respectively, all traditional approaches has the complexity of `O(M * N)` because you need to compare each entry within array `scrape` with the ones exists in array `old` to find out whether matches or not.

The second and more efficient approach is to create a hash table on first array, typically on bigger one (`old` here), and iterate over the second one (`scrape` here) which has the complexity of `O(M + N)`.

If the size of `M` and `N` be as big as enough, the differences show themselves. As an example if `M=100` and `N=200`, the former one needs to compare `20000` objects but the later one needs just `300` comparisons.

please take a look at this code:

```js
const old = [
  {a: 6, b: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 1},
  {a: 3, b: 3}
]

const scrape = [
  {a: 1, b: 1},
  {a: 5, b:5}
]

// create hash map using built-in Javascript Map
const pair = old.map(x => [JSON.stringify(x), true])
const map = new Map(pair)

// filter those object does not exist in hash map
const good = scrape.filter(x => !map.has(JSON.stringify(x)))
console.log(good)
```

Comment: thanks!  I tried your example without the hash map, and it seems to work as well, unless I'm overlooking something?      `var good;
var old1 = old.map(e => JSON.stringify(e));
good = scrape.filter(e=> !old1.includes(JSON.stringify(e)));
console.log(good);`

Comment: @mac It's ok but in large arrays, it takes time because it has complexity of `O(MN)` as described above. Using hash map is efficient way. however, what you have done is also works.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
const good = scrape.filter((sEl) => {
  return !old.some(oEl => oEl.a === sEl.a);
})
```

This avoids the nested forEach loops and `.some` will return as soon as a single true condition is found, avoiding some excess searching when an element exists early in the 'old' array.

Comment: Keep in mind that this only matches based on the key `a`.

Answer (score 0):

May be something like:

```js
var old = [
  {a: 6, b: 3},
  {a: 1, b: 1}, 
  {a: 3, b: 3}
]

var scrape = [
  {a: 1, b: 1}, 
  {a: 5, b:5}
]

var result = scrape.filter(s => old.findIndex(o => o.a === s.a) === -1);
console.log(result);
```